# Select timestamped records for certain amount of the most recent dates with offset support

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Let's assume we have an entity with datetime column.
Spring, jpa, hibernate etc. Good old Oracle 10.

The goal is to get records for certain amount of the most recent dates with days offset support.

For example:

```
ID | TIMESTAMP
 1 | 2019-01-30 11:20:00
 2 | 2019-01-30  5:12:22
 3 | 2019-01-29 23:20:01
 4 | 2019-01-27 12:12:12
 5 | 2019-01-27  1:02:00
```

```
List<MyObject> someMethod(int limit, int offset)
```

someMethod(1, 0) will return records: 1-2
someMethod(3, 0) will return records: 1-5
someMethod(2, 1) will return records: 3-5
someMethod(3, 1) will return records: 3-5

I tried with smth like:

```
        String RECENT_DATES_QUERY = "select dates.DATE_RECEIVED from " +
                "(select distinct trunc(e.DATE_RECEIVED) DATE_RECEIVED from ENTITY e order by 1 desc) dates " +
                "where rownum between 1 + :offset and :offset + :limit order by 1 desc";

        @Query(value = RECENT_DATES_QUERY, nativeQuery = true)
        List<LocalDate> findRecentDatesWithOffset(@Param("limit") int limit, @Param("offset") int offset);
```

to get the dates and later to select * where trunc(timestamp) in ... but there is one big catch. Datasource uses different default schema (alter session). I cannot hardcode schema in the query.

Any idea?

Comment: It could be me but i can't find a pattern in your 'wanted situation': 
someMethod(1, 0) will return records: 1-2
someMethod(3, 0) will return records: 1-5
someMethod(2, 1) will return records: 3-5
someMethod(3, 1) will return records: 3-5

Comment: dates limit 1 offset 0 should return records for the most recent date so records with id 1 and 2 ---
dates limit 3 with offset 0 will return records for three most recent dates so all records in our situation ---
if limit is two dates and offset is 1 we return records for two most recent dates skipping one (so because of the offset we skip 30th) - we return records for 29th and 27th